# Map numbers String to Array of numbers

Tags: javascript, types, numbers

I can't see why this code doesn't produce numbers. Can anyone explain please?

```js
a = '1 3 2 6 1 2'.split(' ');
a = a.map(Number);

for (item in a){
    console.log(typeof(item));
}
```

The output for me in Chrome is 6 strings.

Comment: `item` are the _indexes_, not the values. You probably meant `for (item of a)`.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks. I would mark you answer as the solution but it's only a comment...

Comment: Not sure whether it’s right to answer your question… it’s _almost_ off-topic for being a simple typo (or a “mental” typo). Here are a few things you should have done before asking your question: log `item` directly to verify that you iterate over the values, log the whole array `a` (there should be a distinction in color for strings and numbers), verify if a `for-in` loop iterates over values or indexes via the docs.

Answer (score 1):

#### You need to use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), *not* `for..in` to iterate Arrays:

```js
arr = '1 2 3 4'.split(' ').map(Number) // ["1","2","3","4"] => [1,2,3,4]

for( item of arr ) console.log( typeof(item), item )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = '1 3 2 6 1 2'.split(' ');
a = a.map(Number);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: you were trying to use typeof item which is string because a is object in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating over the content of `a` as you seem to be expecting but are instead iterating on the indexes in your for..in loop.

You can refer to the for..in documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Interesting area is where they talk about using for..in on Arrays (and how you probably shouldn't in a case like this).

If I understand correctly this is what I believe will produce the result you are expecting :

```
for (item in a) { 
   console.log(typeof(a[item]));
}
```

Similarly, to access the elements directly

```
for (item in a) { 
   console.log(a[item]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will be helpful.

```js
var num = 343532;
 var result=num.toString().split('').map(Number);
 console.log(result);
```